# Reading file (using FileReader) and splitting line into two strings in Java

Tags: java, filereader

```
import java.io.*;


public class ReadFile {

public static void read(File f) throws IOException {
    //String delimiters = ".";
    FileReader fr = new FileReader(f);

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

    String line;
    //int numberOfLines = 0;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] tokens = line.split("\\.", 2);
        String p1 = tokens[0];
        String p2 = tokens[1];
        System.out.println(p1);
        System.out.println(p2);
        //numberOfLines++;
    }
    //System.out.println("Numebr of lines in file: " + numberOfLines);
    br.close();
    fr.close();

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    File f = new File("F:\\Dictionary.txt");
    try {
        read(f);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}


}
```

I have a problem in which I'm using a Dictionary as a text file and I want to read the lines (of dictionary file) and then split it up so that I can store the "words" and their "meanings" into different array indexes. This `String[] tokens = line.split("\\.", 2); to read and split at only the first "." (so that words proceeding after "." will be splitted!). I seem to having an error of ArrayIndexOutOfBound and I don't know why. I want`String p1 = tokens[0]; to store the words and `String p12 = tokens[1](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByAbzVqaUg0BSFp5NXNHOGhuOFk); the meanings of the words. How can I do it?
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByAbzVqaUg0BSFp5NXNHOGhuOFk    Link for Dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Your dictionary file is not what your program expects it to be.

There are lines with single letters (like the very first line containing single letter **A**). Then you have plenty of empty lines.

To make your processing more robust make these modifications to your parsing loop:

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    //skip empty lines
    if (line.length() <= 1) {
        continue;
    }
    try {
        String[] tokens = line.split("\\.", 2);
        String p1 = tokens[0];
        String p2 = tokens[1];
        System.out.println(p1);
        System.out.println(p2);
    } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        //catch index out of bounds and see why
        System.out.println("PROBLEM with line: " + line);
    }
}
```